# Let's handle doomed tag synonym suggestions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

For a tag synonym to be approved, it needs to garner four upvotes, and only users with an answer score of at least five in the target tag are allowed to vote. As I showed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/265817/253560) (Stack Exchange Data Explorer query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/360325/doomed-tag-suggestions)), 48 of our 750 pending tag synonyms on Stack Overflow (as of the last data dump) could not possibly be approved because there aren't five users with sufficient answer score (one to propose and four to upvote). For these "doomed" tag synonym suggestions to be approved, we need to take action on meta (or wait for more users to get upvotes on answers in the target tag).

The following are doomed suggestions that seemed correct to me (either from tag wikis or from web searching -- see the notes I left). It would be great to hear community feedback about this list, and if the community agrees then I think it would be great if a moderator could approve these synonyms (the community cannot do so on its own under the current tag synonym voting rules).

```
            SourceTagName             TargetTagName Score numVoters sourceQs tgtQs
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          atlassian-crowd                     crowd     0         4       11    49  # The [crowd] tag wiki excerpt indicates it's a SSO tool, and Google query "crowd SSO" yields https://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview, so it seems [crowd] refers to a software tool by Atlassian
               lpsolveapi                   lpsolve     0         4       12    90  # I proposed this one -- lpsolveapi is an API to access the lpsolve linear programming solver
                      wtk     java-wireless-toolkit     0         4       44    31  # The [wtk] tag wiki excerpt is "Java ME Wireless Toolkit"
                      muc             multiuserchat     0         3       36    81  # Both tag wikis indicate these tags refer to the same XMPP protocol extension 
              f#-charting               fsharpchart     0         3       14    19  # The tag wiki excerpt for [f#-charting] indicates it's about FSharp.Charting.dll, which is the topic of the [fsharpchart] questions.
               nokia-maps                 here-maps     0         3      205   153  # From the [here-maps] tag wiki excerpt, it used to be called Nokia maps
                 javacaps                     jcaps     0         1        3    12  # All [javacaps] are also tagged [jcaps], and the [jcaps] tag wiki excerpt indicates that it's a java software suite
        facebook-java-sdk         facebook-java-api     0         1       25    51  # A lot of questions are tagged with both, and the names seem to suggest they're pretty much the same thing
                     jazz                  ibm-jazz     0         1       87    33  # Tag wiki excerpt for [jazz] indicates it's for "IBM Jazz family of products"
```

The following are doomed suggestions I think are actually synonyms but for which I was not sure if the proposed direction makes the most sense. **Update: these three synonyms have now been added (the first and last were reversed and the middle was kept in the direction proposed).**

```
            SourceTagName             TargetTagName Score numVoters sourceQs tgtQs
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    c3.js                        c3     0         4      141   149  # We have [d3] as a synonym of [d3.js], so I think that makes more sense here
                      msp                 msi-patch     0         3       58    12  # The [msi-patch] tag wiki excerpt indicates it's about .msp files, so it's clear there's a synonym. I don't have a clear sense of what should be a synonym of the other.
  clearcase-remote-client                      ccrc     0         1       62    46
```

The following are additional doomed suggestions that are less obvious to me (either I disagree or feel I don't know enough to comment) and that I think we should discuss as a community and then decide how to act:

```
            SourceTagName             TargetTagName Score numVoters sourceQs tgtQs
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                spring-dm    springsource-dm-server     1         1       70    29
                  execute                    firing     0         4      798    54
                     rtsj            real-time-java     0         4        8    17
      spring-data-mongodb      spring-data-document     0         4      684     9
                groupchat             multiuserchat     0         3       12    81
             tpagecontrol               pagecontrol     0         2       35    50
      firebasesimplelogin   firebase-authentication     0         1      140    54
                   sesame                   openrdf     0         1      210    18
                powerpack                powerpacks     0         0       22    39
                garnet-os                   palm-os    -1         4       11    39
```

Finally, the following suggestions could probably be cleaned up, as either the source or target tag (or both) has no associated questions:

```
            SourceTagName             TargetTagName Score numVoters sourceQs tgtQs
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   kinect                     natal     2         0     2267     0
        blackberry-widget        blackberry-widgets     2         0        0    21
                workplace          work-environment     1         0        0     0
   apache-commons-logging   jakarta-commons-logging     1         0      148     0
               generating                generation     1         0        0     0
                  pure.js                   pure-js     0         3        0    19
             visual-build visual-build-professional     0         2        0     9
        date-manipulation              manipulation     0         0       36     0
           memory-address                   address     0         0      738     0
              large-scale                     large     0         0       23     0
          mediafoundation  windows-media-foundation     0         0        0     0
            case-changing          case-sensitivity     0         0        0     0
                   denali           sql-server-2011     0         0        0     0
             catamorphism            catamporphisms     0         0       19     0
            self-teaching          self-improvement     0         0        0     0
           turing-machine                    turing     0         0        0     0
    kernighan-and-ritchie                       knr     0         0      160     0
                boost-mpl                       mpl     0         0      232     0
 programming-fundamentals              fundamentals     0         0        0     0
         spring-dm-server    springsource-dm-server    -1         1        0    29
                 codegear                   borland    -1         0        0     0
             dynamics-nav    microsoft-dynamics-crm    -1         0      145     0
                 truetype                       ttf    -1         0       52     0
```

Comment: @pnuts interesting idea! I'm not sure how well it would scale to Stack Overflow (right now we have 750 pending tag synonym suggestions), but it seems like it would make a nice central place for synonym requests.

Comment: Would it make sense to warn users suggesting these _doomed synonyms_ that they can't be resolved without a meta post and subsequent moderator intervention?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom sounds like a feature request I would get behind!

Comment: I would prefer having [tag:atlassian-crowd] as master for [tag:atlassian], but otherwise the first list has my approval. While I'm not sure about your second list either, I would prefer making the longer tag the master each time there, it's obscure enough that should be its own reward. The third list needs to be confirmed, I simply don't know. And all in the last list look irrelevant or actively harmful.

Comment: @Deduplicator thanks for looking through these! Just to clarify, do you mean make [tag:atlassian-crowd] the master for [tag:crowd], aka flip the proposed synonym? As I see it [tag:atlassian] is different from both.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: A doomed pairing I don't see here:  [tag:google-scripts] -> [tag:google-apps-script]. There are 0 [tag:google-scripts] questions.

Comment: Related - [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work), [Tag synonym system could be improved or given more publicity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181940/tag-synonym-system-could-be-improved-or-given-more-publicity). There's really no reason there should be as many as 700 outstanding suggestions IMO (not to mention the numerous "suggestions" that no-one has suggested, probably because of the silly limitation on suggesting that's generally inconsistent with other requirements).

Comment: @mogsdad this is the list of suggestions for which fewer than 5 have answer score of at least 5 in the target tag. Therefore the relevant quantity is the number of eligible voters for [google-app-script], not the number of eligible voters for [google-scripts].

Comment: @josilber Thanks for the clarification - a misread on my part.

Comment: @dukeling I definitely agree that having so many pending suggestions is problematic! I also recently added a new proposal to get the list of synonym suggestions to a more reasonable size: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305405/3093387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following 10 doomed tag synonym proposals are now approved:

- [crowd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crowd) -> [atlassian-crowd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-crowd)
- [lpsolveapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lpsolveapi) -> [lpsolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lpsolve)
- [wtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wtk) -> [java-wireless-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-wireless-toolkit)
- [muc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/muc) -> [multiuserchat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiuserchat)
- [f#-charting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23-charting) -> [fsharpchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fsharpchart)
- [facebook-java-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-java-sdk) -> [facebook-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-java-api)
- [jazz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jazz) -> [ibm-jazz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-jazz)
- [c3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c3) -> [c3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c3.js)
- [msp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msp) -> [msi-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msi-patch)
- [ccrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ccrc) -> [clearcase-remote-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clearcase-remote-client)

25 doomed tag synonym proposals were removed due to having no questions in either the target or source tag (or both).

Answer (score 6):

Cross-posting this answer with what I posted [on your other topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305549) about synonyms as I feel it's very relevant here:

> Whilst on the subject of tag synonyms, I'm going to bring up this *issue*:
>
> > [image: Tag Synonym Error 1]
>
> > [image: Tag Synonym Error 2]
>
> I imagine there would be far fewer tag synonyms to handle if a new [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) was set up to allow trusted users to bypass the above error messages.
>
> ## [Can we allow 7.5K users to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag)
>
> This is a long-standing topic (with a score of +140/-6) about this on SE's Meta posted back in 2011 which received [an official response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154759/211113) from [Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) over a year later which a lot of people have disagreed with. Back in October 2013 I posted in the same topic [pointing out flaws in Shog9's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203760/211113) (which featured the first image displayed above). I've also offered [2 separate bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/103213/revisions) on the same topic asking for an official response to my reply which unfortunately went ignored.
>
> I'd really like to see an updated official response to that, and I feel it'd certainly help with this issue.