# Let's handle the backlog of tag synonym suggestions

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

#### Problem

As of the last Stack Exchange data dump, there were 750 pending tag synonym suggestions on Stack Overflow. Given that only 2,406 tag synonyms have been approved (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/265817/253560) for the breakdown at SO and other top Stack Exchange sites) and that [on average pending synonyms have been around for nearly half a year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244/253560), this represents a large backlog. Because of the [important](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) [role](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2779/253560) tag synonyms play in organizing material on Stack Overflow, I think the long delays for synonym review and the large backlog are problematic.

#### Proposal

I propose that we as a community use our voting power to knock down this backlog of tag synonym proposals!

#### Why This Could Work

In short, I think this could work because the vast majority of pending tag synonym suggestions can be voted on by 10 or more users (more than half can be voted on by 100 or more users). If even a modest proportion of those who can vote do so, then we can significantly reduce the backlog.

In more detail, tag synonyms silently map from a source to a target tag, listed as "Synonym" and "Master," respectively, on the [tag synonyms list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms). Any 2.5k+ user with answer score of at least 5 in the target tag can propose a synonym, and any user with answer score of at least 5 in the target tag can vote on the proposed synonym; synonyms are approved at score 4 and rejected at score -2 (full details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/253560)). This makes it hard to approve tag synonyms in low-volume tags (if interested, check out [my proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305388/3093387) regarding this issue). However, many proposed tag synonyms have popular target tags with many potential voters:

- 666 proposed synonyms (89%) can be voted on by 10 or more users
- 584 proposed synonyms (78%) can be voted on by 25 or more users
- 383 proposed synonyms (51%) can be voted on by 100 or more users
- 72 proposed synonyms (10%) can be voted on by 1000 or more users

I think a concerted push by the community to vote on proposed tag synonyms about which they're familiar could make a real dent in the backlog.

#### How to Vote

The tag synonyms that you can vote on (aka the ones for which you have answer score of at least 5 on the target tag) are accessible at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest. On this page, the source tag (the one that will be silently renamed) is labeled "Synonym," and the target tag is labeled "Master." You can click on each target (master) tag to view all approved synonyms and to vote on all proposed synonyms. Care should be taken in voting (e.g. reading tag wikis and looking through lists of questions with each tag), since [bad tag synonyms can only be reversed by a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/253560).

To find other users who can vote on a tag synonym, enter the target (master) tag into [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/361199).

Comment: Nice idea. This reminds me of a couple of wrong synonyms that I suggested for the [less] tag and are still pending since 2014. I would be very happy if somebody can reject them but unfortunately there are very few active users in the [less] tag. I think the tag synonym suggestions should be moved to a more prominent place (say like the info box that is shown on the Tag questions page). Was already thinking of posting this as a feature request for the new UI.

Comment: @Harry yeah, UI improvements would be awesome, and would make it easier to find and understand the tag synonym vote page -- there have been some good proposals already (e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197656/253560) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202754/253560) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244/253560)). Still, I think we can make progress on this even without UI improvements!

Comment: Odd... I proposed a tag synonym in May 2013, [tag:google-scripts] -> [tag:google-apps-script]. Nothing happened, so I retagged several hundred questions, and [tag:google-scripts] went away. However, the synonym request still shows up. With no questions on the synonym, it's impossible for anybody to vote on. Now what?

Comment: @Mogsdad you won't be able to vote on it because you proposed it, but anybody with 5+ answer score in the target tag ([tag:google-apps-script]) will be able to vote. You can look up all the others who can vote [with this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/361199?tag=google-apps-script) -- it looks like 235 other users can vote.

Comment: I don't exactly agree with lumping all the (k,x,l)ubuntu under ubuntu. In all these cases they do not use the "Unity" desktop engine and that does make them different. I hate looking for a solution for lubuntu and get answers that don't relate because they are actually for ubuntu.

Comment: Note that where the proposed synonym tag has zero questions, the synonym should be rejected.  There are a number of proposals like that (for example: `tz` as a synonym of `timezone`; `identifiers` as a synonym of `identifier`; `implementations` as a synonym of `implementation`).  There are a number where the proposed synonym only has a few questions; those should simply be retagged, not synonymized (`tz` had that happen — 14 questions, a number of which also had the `timezone` tag already; `libgmp` had 2 questions); there are others like that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point that the synonym doesn't seem to be achieving much once there are no questions to be synonymized. Auto-rejecting a suggestion once the source tag has no questions sounds like a good feature request. It would clear out 98 of our current pending synonym suggestions.

Comment: @JRSofty: that's a problem where there's really no way of providing information (for or against) a synonymization request.  It would be good if people could explain why they agree or disagree with them.  It would require some extra UI from the SO developers, though.

Comment: Does anyone want to create a synonym suggestion that [tag:percent-encoding] (66 questions) should be a synonym of [tag:url-encoding] (690-odd questions)?  I don't have the points in url-encoding to be able to do it, but the wiki's are similar (no big surprise there).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler none of the 115 users (not including mods) who can create the synonym have commented here. You can see the list with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/361199).

Answer (score 13):

Whilst on the subject of tag synonyms, I'm going to bring up this *issue*:

> [image: Tag Synonym Error 1]

> [image: Tag Synonym Error 2]

I imagine there would be far fewer tag synonyms to handle if a new [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) was set up to allow trusted users to bypass the above error messages.

## [Can we allow 7.5K users to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag)

This is a long-standing topic (with a score of +140/-6) about this on SE's Meta posted back in 2011 which received [an official response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154759/211113) from [Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) over a year later which a lot of people have disagreed with. Back in October 2013 I posted in the same topic [pointing out flaws in Shog9's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203760/211113) (which featured the first image displayed above). I've also offered [2 separate bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/103213/revisions) on the same topic asking for an official response to my reply which unfortunately went ignored.

I'd really like to see an updated official response to that, and I feel it'd certainly help with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link to your excellent meta.se answer -- I definitely agree that expanding who can vote on tag synonyms could help address the backlog. Still, my goal here was to point out that even under the current voting rules, we as a community can address much of the backlog by voting on the proposed synonyms listed at the link I included in the question.

Answer (score 5):

[List of tag-synonyms and assessment](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest):

[move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/move) ← [move-semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/move-semantics) ok
[stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) ← [c++-standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-standard-library) They are different, as both tag-wikis clarify.
[makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) ← [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make) Should be the other way around.
[variadic-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-functions) ← [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/varargs) ok
[modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulo) ← [modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulus) ok
[ctor-initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctor-initializer) ← [initialization-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialization-list) no, look especially at the non-C++ uses.
[factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory) ← [factory-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-pattern) ok

Comment: [tag:stl] and [tag:c++-standard-library] should be reversed since the STL is a subset of the C++ standard library and I think no one would spot the difference and care anyway. If the C++ standard library tag exists STL is not a useful additional tag anymore.

Comment: @nwp: [tag:stl] is no more useful than the [tag:libc++] and [tag:libstdc++] tags, sure. Which just means it's *rarely* relevant, but sometimes it actually is.

Comment: @nwp Implying that no one would spot the difference or care? I've met a LOT of people in the C++ chat that would probably beg to differ. Besides, there are many minute concepts in C++ that are very important to get right, like SFINAE, MVP, move semantics, and CRTP; while this isn't quite as important, it's definitely a sore spot among Lounge participants (many of which are extremely active on SO, and  which roughly represent the front-line in answering legitimate C++ questions).

Comment: @ShotgunNinja The difference between STL and Standard Library isn't one of those important minute concepts. Maybe I just completely missed that aspect of C++ pedantry but I don't see anyone protesting against the synonym.

Comment: @nwp: So, what would you say to merging [tag:.net] and [tag:mono]? Or maybe merge [tag:windows] and [tag:winapi] and [tag:wine]?

Comment: @Deduplicator I would say no to those.

Comment: @nwp: Well, what's the difference to synonymizing stl and c++-standard-library?

Comment: The difference is that those other tags are actually different. WinApi questions I can give a shot because I am somewhat experienced, Wine I have never really used and have no idea about the completeness of the project. Someone saying _I know the STL by heart but can't help you with the c++ standard library_ just doesn't happen. But maybe other people have different experience (ideally if they are personally affected by the merge), so let the votes decide. I can't vote so my opinion doesn't count anyways.

Comment: [tag:modulo] and [tag:modulus] still need more synonym votes.

Answer (score 1):

#### Overview of Progress

Of the original 750 proposed synonyms, we have **698 (93%)** remaining. The total number of pending tag synonyms is **714**. We still have some work to go to get through the backlog!

#### Proposed Synonyms with the Largest Number of Eligible Voters

The following are the top 25 currently proposed tag synonyms that we as a community should have the easiest time approving or rejecting because they have the largest number of eligible voters (SEDE query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/360439/info-about-pending-tag-synonyms), plus manual updates based on the suggested tag synonyms page):

```
            SourceTagName   TargetTagName Score numVoters sourceQs  tgtQs ageDays
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            tableviewcell     uitableview     0      4333      374  39503     136
                  lubuntu          ubuntu     3      3721       30  24135      66
                  kubuntu          ubuntu     3      3721      122  24135      66
                  xubuntu          ubuntu     3      3721      101  24135      66
         wordpress-widget       wordpress     3      3593      136  77607     321
         wordpress-filter       wordpress     2      3593       31  77607     321
             wordpress-mu       wordpress     3      3593      278  77607     321
     wordpress-plugin-dev       wordpress     2      3593     1535  77607     321
                 wp-query       wordpress     0      3593      342  77607       0
                      tsv             csv     2      3101      241  27326       0
      codeigniter-routing     codeigniter     2      2914      279  38625     103
  codeigniter-form-helper     codeigniter     2      2914      116  38625     103
 codeigniter-activerecord     codeigniter     2      2914       20  38625      53
          codeigniter-url     codeigniter     2      2914      451  38625     103
   codeigniter-pagination     codeigniter     1      2914       20  38625      52
   codeigniter-validation     codeigniter     2      2914       12  38625      99
                    login  authentication     1      2898    12913  23683     298
         android-listview        listview     1      2754    14834  30633       0
                plaintext            text     1      2693      325  16361     586
    concurrency-violation     concurrency     2      2506        7  10877     109
          rotateanimation       animation     1      2488       94  23033     674
           scaleanimation       animation     1      2488       28  23033     674
                 animated       animation     1      2488      311  23033     674
            schema-design database-design     2      2427      131  15573     340
      active-record-query    activerecord     1      2386       51  18601      61
```

Comment: @pnuts: given the tag description of [tag:plaintext], it is appropriate.  If the tag was about 'plaintext vs ciphertext', then maybe not.  I've not checked the question content in detail. _[…later…]_ Hmmm; two questions out of the first fifty I see tagged 'plaintext' are related to cryptography, and one of those probably doesn't need any sort of 'text' tag.  On the whole, the synonym looks valid — though I'd not object to it being rejected if the plaintext tag wiki is updated.

Comment: I'm going to be curious to see what happens with [tag:concurrency-violation].  It's a sponsored tag, but there are no questions left tagged with the tag.

Comment: @pnuts I like that idea -- adding comments to go with tag synonym suggestions is one of the many proposals [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244/253560).

Comment: @pnuts I guess we could always add a bounty!

Comment: @pnuts haha it wasn't my question

Comment: @pnuts: I'm not sure it's my place to disabuse you of the notion.  My conception is equally as suspect as yours.  I don't have a specific use for [tag:plaintext].  On the whole, I'd rather that it was retagged out of current use rather than synonymized; I think it could have use as a crypto-related tag. Against that, there'd seldom be a need for plaintext and ciphertext as tags; any question about encryption or decryption probably involves plaintext and ciphertext.