# What is the difference between the [make] and [makefile] tags?

Tags: discussion

Searching for content related to Make, I found that [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make) and [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) are used very similarly. Also the tag descriptions didn't really give away which types of questions should belong to one but not the other.

Of course I am aware that technically,

- [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make) could be related more to the tool itself, i.e. how to run it, command-line options, passing variables etc. while
- [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) could be more about writing rules, syntax and the like.

But in practice, it seems this distinction is often hard to make (pun intended) ...so I am wondering if those tags really should be merged, since a search for [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) tagged questions might miss some relevant questions tagged just [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make) and vice versa.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305509: The synonym was already proposed in the wrong direction. Unfortunately, I get an unexpected error when proposing the right synonym... maybe we need a mod to look into it.

Comment: @Deduplicator thanks for the pointer. How would we go about getting a mod involved?