# Why tag synonyms doesn't get attention

Tags: discussion, support

i suggested a tag synonym for `sql` from about 2 month but until now it is not accepted or rejected. my question is why not showing the suggested synonyms number on the tag wiki an how can i get more attention to a suggested synonym?

[image]

**my synonym suggestion**

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/synonyms

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305405/lets-handle-the-backlog-of-tag-synonym-suggestions